# Replace a particular substring in a list of string with another substring

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I am taking an example scenario for my question.
If I have a list of URLs :

```
url_list=["https:www.example.com/pag31/go","https:www.example.com/pag12/go","https:www.example.com/pag0/go"]
```

I want to replace the substring in between ".com/" and "go"

For Eg. new url should look like

```
['https:www.example.com/home/go','https:www.example.com/home/go','https:www.example.com/home/go']
```

I have tried slicing and replacing based on index but couldn't get the required result for the whole list.

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regex` `sub()` and list comprehension to apply your logic to every element of your list.

```
import re

url_list=["https:www.google.com/pag31/go","https:www.facebook.com/pag12/go","http:www.bing.com/pag0/go"]

pattern = r'(?<=com\/).*(?=\/go)'

result = [re.sub(pattern, 'home', url) for url in url_list]
```

This will match against any string where a value is found between `com/` and `/go`. This will also ensure that we capture any website, regardless of http(s).

Output:

```
['https:www.google.com/home/go', 'https:www.facebook.com/home/go', 'http:www.bing.com/home/go']
```

---

**Regex Explanation**

The pattern `r'(?<=com\/).*(?=\/go)'` looks for the following:

`(?<=com\/)`: Positive lookbehind to check if `com/` prefixes our lookup

`.*`: Matches anything an infinite amount of times

`(?=\/go)`: Positive look ahead to check if `/go` directly occurs after `.*`

This enables us to match any string between the positive checks. You can find a more in-depth explanation on the pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/2TSJUE/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) of python.

```
import re
re_url ="https:www.example.com/.*/go"
url = "https:www.example.com/home/go"
url_list_new= [re.sub(re_url,url,x) for x in url_list]
url_list_new
```

Output:

```
 ['https:www.example.com/home/go',
 'https:www.example.com/home/go',
 'https:www.example.com/home/go']
```

Comment: This will only work against the `example` the poster has listed. If any other URL other then example are in the list, or even a `http` url it will not match.

Comment: @PacketLoss yes right. I missed that thing, thanks for pointing out.